# g++ Undefined reference to base class destructor and derived class pointer

Tags: c++

Edit: I had forgotten to explicitly define my class destructors in their respective .cpp files. I replaced `*p` with `string *killList = new string[10];`
and my code now compiles. Thanks for your replies!

I've tried to compile the following files using the command :

```
g++ -o hunter hunter_h.h hunter_h.cpp animal_h.h animal_h.cpp main.cpp
```

**animal_h.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
using namespace std;

// Animal class 
class animal
{
    friend class hunter;
    // need a name, species, private ID
public: 
    animal();
    animal(string aSpecies);
    string name;
    string species;
    string getSpecies();
    void setName(string aName);
    string getName();
    int getID();
    ~animal();

private:
    static int uID;

};



#endif
```

**animal_h.cpp**

```
#include "animal_h.h"
//#include "hunter_h.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int animal:: uID = 0 ;



animal::animal()
{
    cout << "Created an animal!" << endl;
    name = "?";
    species = "?";
    uID++;
}



animal::animal(string aSpecies)
{
    cout << "Created 1 "<< aSpecies << "!" << endl;
    name= "?";
    species = aSpecies;
    uID++;
}




string animal::getSpecies()
{
    cout << species << endl;
}



void animal::setName(string aName)
{
    name = aName;
    cout << "This " << species << " is now called " << name << endl;
}


string animal::getName()
{
    cout << name << endl;
}


int animal:: getID()
{
    cout << uID << endl; 
}
```

**hunter_h.h** This is a derived class of the animal base class with unique behaviors.

```
#include "animal_h.h"
#include <iostream>
#ifndef ANIMAL_HUNTER
#define ANIMAL_HUNTER

class hunter : public animal 
{
public: 
    hunter();
    hunter(std::string aSpecies);
    void recordKills(std::string kill);
    static int tKills; 
    int totalKills(); 
    static std::string *theKills();
    static std::string *p;
    static int clearTotal();
    ~hunter();
};
#endif
```

**hunter_h.cpp**

```
#include "animal_h.h"
#include "hunter_h.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int hunter:: tKills =0;
string killList[10];

hunter::hunter()  
{
    cout<<"created a hunter! "<<endl;
    name= "? ";
    species="? ";
    string *p;
    p = &killList[0];


}

hunter::hunter(string aSpecies) 
{
    name = "?";
    species = aSpecies;
    cout << "created a hunting "<<species <<endl;


}

string *theKills() 
{
    return hunter::p;
} 

void hunter::recordKills(string kill) 
{   
    cout << kill << " killed." << endl; 
    *(p+tKills) = kill;
    tKills++;
    cout << tKills << " total kills." << endl;

}   

int hunter::totalKills()
{
    cout << name << "'s " << "Total kills: " << tKills << endl;
}   
int hunter::clearTotal()
{
    delete[] killList;
    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "animal_h.h"
#include "hunter_h.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    hunter *hunterC;
    hunterC= new hunter("cheetah");
    hunterC->recordKills("Mouse");
    hunterC-> recordKills("Gazelle, Gazelle");
    hunterC-> recordKills("Hyena");
    hunterC-> recordKills("Rabbit, Rabbit");
    hunterC->theKills; 
    hunterC->clearTotal;



}
```

Now, when I try to compile I get the following warning and errors:

```
hunter_h.cpp: In static member function ‘static int hunter::clearTotal()’:
hunter_h.cpp:49:11: warning: deleting array ‘killList’
  delete[] killList;
           ^
/tmp/ccnv8xdj.o:hunter_h.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `animal::~animal()'
/tmp/ccnv8xdj.o:hunter_h.cpp:(.text+0x101): undefined reference to `animal::~animal()'
/tmp/ccnv8xdj.o:hunter_h.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `hunter::p'
/tmp/ccnv8xdj.o:hunter_h.cpp:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `hunter::p'
/tmp/ccqCD1e7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `animal::~animal()'
/tmp/ccqCD1e7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `animal::~animal()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've been learning C++ for a couple months only so am not sure where the above code is going wrong. How can I get this to compile and run?

Comment: if you are declaring a destructor of animal explicitly, you need to define it in .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that and now only get the undefined reference to hunter::p errors

Comment: Your usage of `hunter::p` confuses me. I don't think you understand what you're trying to do with it. What is it for? Why is it `static`? Why is it a `string*` and not a `string`?

Comment: hunter::p is meant to be a pointer to the array of recorded kills by a hunter

Comment: as it's static, you have to define it in hunter_h.cpp, like `std::string* hunter::p=NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

killList is not allocated using new[], then dont delete it with delete[]. It is not allocated runtime, then it does not have to be deallocated explicitly. It will release its memory when the program exits. With your code as it is you are running the chance of overrunning you killList array.

Try using std::vector instead.

```
std::vector<std::string> killList;

...

void recordKills(std::string s)
{
...
    killList.push_back(s);
}

void clearTotal()
{
    killList.clear();
}
```